# Read from textfile to textfield java

Tags: java

I have a text file which stores data about a user, from username, password and other details. In the text file, each user's data is stored in one line and separated using ",". I am trying to read from the file and list all the usernames. usernames are first one the line

In the following code, I manage to read and output, but only the last one from the text file. How can I read and output all.

```
try {
        File f = new File("/Users/Nisham/Desktop/javapwd.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);



        while(sc.hasNextLine()){

            String line = sc.nextLine();
            String[] details = line.split(",");
            String name = details[0];
            //int age = Integer.parseInt(details[2]);
            jTextArea1.setText(name);

        }



    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {         
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with networking, netbeans, or bufferedreader.

Answer (score 2):

Each time through the while loop you reset the text to the newly read input, wiping out the previous text. You need to append the text, not set it.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the text in jTextArea1 in while loop

```
jTextArea1.setText(name);
```